# Override default store function of a controller in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I am working on a Laravel application that has some modules implemented.
Now, the one of the modules extends a default controller and should be able to override the default store() function

I tried the following:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
    
class OriginalController extends AdminBaseController
    {
        public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $model = new Model();
            $model->name = $request->name;
            $model->save();
        }
    }
```

In the module:

```
namespace Modules\CustomModule\Http\Controllers\Admin;

    class ExtendedController extends OriginalController
    {
        public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $model = new Model();
            $model->name = $request->name;
            $model->newInfo = $request->newInfo;
            $model->save();
        }
    }
```

Even if I set the web.php routes for the new controller, the store() function will only look at the original one
Could someone tell me what am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: You are not missing anything, this is the right way to override `store` method. 

Please provide some more information and debug information. What is happening, how do you know that it calls original store method, instead of extended one?

Comment: If you loog at the extended class, the store function has a $request->newInfo. That one doesn't get stored, even if the blade page has it..

Comment: just ensure hat the request is reaching your extended controller method by using something like dd() in that method , and I suggest you clear the route cache

Comment: Already did that, that's why I am asking here :) I did a clear cache as well, nothing works..

Comment: "Already did that", so ... show your minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, we can't guess what you already did, you have to show it. `dd();` is your friend, so is the laravel.log. show the output of those things that are asked